# poll() return type conflict with PriorityBlockingQueue.poll()

Tags: java, priority-queue, fifo

In the below poll() method, my IDE is complaining about the fact that it returns JobSet.  Tooltip reads: **poll() in my.package.JobSetQueue clashes with poll() in  java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue; attempting to use an incompatible return type**

How come I can't use whatever return type I want here?

```
public class JobSetQueue extends PriorityBlockingQueue<FIFOEntry<JobSet>> {
    public JobSetQueue() {
        super(1, new JobSetComparator());
    }

    public boolean add(JobSet jobSet) {
        return super.add(new FIFOEntry<JobSet>(jobSet));
    }

    public JobSet poll() {
        /*FIFOEntry<JobSet> entry = super.poll();
        return entry.getEntry();*/
        return super.poll().getEntry();
    }
}



public class FIFOEntry<T> {
    final static AtomicLong seq = new AtomicLong();
    private final long sequenceNumber;
    private final T entry;

    public FIFOEntry(T entry) {
        sequenceNumber = seq.getAndIncrement();
        this.entry = entry;
    }

    public long getSequenceNumber() {
        return sequenceNumber;
    }

    public T getEntry() {
        return entry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`PriorityBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html) already has a method [`poll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#poll%28%29) with a generic return type. You cannot override a method and change its return type to some incompatible type, see the JLS section for [method overrides](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4) and the section for [method return types `return-type-substitutable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5).

In your case, `PriorityBlockingQueue<FIFOEntry<JobSet>>` would expect `poll()` to return `FIFOEntry<JobSet>`.